# Azure data sync is in processing state, how do I know how long it will take to complete?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I am processing around 12GB of data from hub to destination, and both databases are Azure SQL Databases. I see a lag of more than 18hrs. And Sync is in processing state for more than 14 hrs. How do I know how long it will take to complete?.

Current log status is :

1549802 rows have been processed in 52609 seconds.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Data Sync won't know the two databases are identical until it compares the data row by row. It is a very costly process and may take a long time if you have large databases/tables. My recommendation is to have data only on one side and keep the same table empty in the other databases. In this case, data sync will use bulk load during initialization, and it is much faster than row by row comparison.

Scale up the service tiers of Azure SQL databases during initial sync should speed up things too.

To get information of the state (Ready, Not Ready) of a sync group you can use PowerShell cmdlet [Get-AzureRmSqlSyncGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqlsyncgroup?view=azurermps-6.13.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-5.0.0). I don't know a way to get the progress of the first synchronization.